# ASP.NET application not loading javascript

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am developing an application on my win XP box.  I use visual web dev to run the app interactively but I have also set it up on IIS for testing from another machine on my network.  This all worked perfectly until...

Microsoft had a high priority update in the form of IE8 and after the update failed to reboot.  After a silly amount to tinkering and tweaking, the eventual solution was a repair install of XP.

So back to the present day and the site continues to run fine interactively (in VWD's built-in web server) but in IIS (via localhost on this machine, IP or hostname from the test machine) the site loads, ASP works, CSS is fine, but javascript does not load.  When I inspect with Firebug, the script references return a 403.2, forbidden access.

Checked the permissions, everything looks fine and dandy.  The same as the root and every other folder, anyway.  IIS has script execution & read on the directory.

I can still develop locally and everything works fine on the server, so this is not an absolute must fix, but it sure bugs the heck out of me.

Answer (score 1):

I asked my question and then immediately jetted off on holiday.  Poor form - sorry.

Thanks for the answers/suggestions. Checked my assemblies, scripting is on, and triple checked permissions - which got me thinking.  Poking around a bit in IIS and discovered that, for whatever reason, the /scripts folder had been made a virtual directory.  Undid that and everything snapped together right as rain.

Thanks again for the assistance.  It got me going in the right direction.

-jerry

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to deploy new versions of binary assemblies? It's the kind of error I got recently when I made ajax call, 403 was result, and binary assemblies just were not copied on server, the new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check whether the Active Scripting is enabled or not ? Please go to IE -> Tools -> Internet Options -> Now depends on where your site is resided at -> go to custom level -> and scroll down, until you see the Active Scripting option. Make sure it's checked.

Thanks,

hadi teo

Comment: Given that FireFox was returning a 403.2, I would doubt that the issue is specific to IE or that any IE configuration tweaks will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Double check permissions :)

Check if you can you load any js file from another other local website/directory.

Has a handler been added (somehow) to deal with .js files?...in the Applicataion Configuration settings or in the web.config?...shouldn't be one.

Are there any Web Service Extensions permission that are setting "Prohibited" for .js ?

Try resetting .net for iis by running:

%WINDIR%\System32\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis -i