# Simple javascript doesn't appear to run in page produces with ASP.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to add a small bit of javascript to an existing Asp.Net MVC application. I have not been able to get the javascript to work, and so I tried creating a simple page to showcase the problem.

The code works when you just open it in a browser, however if the webpage provided by my application it does not work - the onsubmit function is never called.

The actual source code is identical in both situation, the only difference is in the success case I open the html file directly. In the failure case it is returned by my app.

I think there must be some kind of communication between the web app and the browser that disables javascript, but I don't know what it would be.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<script>
    function dontSubmit() {
 alert("You pressed submit");
 return false;
}
</script>

<form action="http://www.google.com/" method="POST" onsubmit="return dontSubmit();">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us the view that generates this page

Comment: Did you try any of these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079479/asp-net-application-not-loading-javascript

Comment: can you please sow a sample of your `_Laout.cshtml` page?

Comment: did you try run debug mode in your browser with developer console(f12)?